# Replicate the effect of the first. function in SAS within SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What is the simplest way (in terms of easily understandable code, not code length or efficiency) to replicate the effect of the first. function in SAS?

```
Select sum(amount), order_id, 
From tablename
Group By order_id
/* Pseudo code below */
Having first.amount = $100
Order by date
```

What I'm trying to do above is to get the total amount for each order but exclude all order_id for which the first transaction date has an amount > 100. If there are multiple amounts for the same date, then only 1 needs to fit the criteria for the whole order to be removed.

For example, the following orders should be removed

```
Order_ID   Date Amount
 1         1/1  45
 1         1/1  100
 1         1/2  32
 2         1/1  100
```

The following orders should NOT be removed

```
 Order_ID   Date Amount
 3         1/1  99.99
 3         1/2  100
 4         1/1  9
 4         1/2  100
```

Answer (score 0):

I see.  You are referring to the `first` variables in a by-processing loop.  Your question is pretty unclear.

This is a bit complicated, because the "first" appears to be needed *after* the aggregation, but it only applies to the first date.  I'm not sure what this code would look like in SAS, but the following should have the same effect SQL:

```
select order_id, sum(amount)
from t
where (select top 1 sum(amount) as first_amount
       from t
       where t2.order_id = t.order_id
       group by date
       order by date
     ) < 100
group by order_id;
```